# DOTS Tasklets access to XPages OSGi Container

Tags: xpages

Does a DOTS tasklet have access to in memory objects residing in the XPages OSGi container?

simple use case:

1. value object posted to server via RESTful service
2. service stores the value object in memory of a concurrent queue
3. tasklet polls queue every n seconds to process value object(s)

Is this possible with DOTS, or does DOTS assume the object will be persisted to disk as a document before a tasklet can process its data?

thanks

-Mark

Comment: You may want to look into this for XPages-DOTS-interactions http://de.slideshare.net/sbasegmez/iconuk-2013-an-xpagers-guide-to-process-serverside-jobs-on-ibm-domino

Comment: found the answer in the slide deck.  "There is almost no connection between DOTS and XPages".  That's too bad, my simple use case won't work.  thanks for the info.  please re-post and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: I think you will need to look at Jobs and Threads in Java. On OpenNTF is project with examples. http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Threads%20and%20Jobs

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I do already have an implementation that is working for me using ScheduledExecutorService inside an ext-lib.  I just wanted to review DOTS as it looks to be the future for background processing in XWork server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this, this is (almost) imposible:

[An XPager's Guide to Process Server-Side Jobs on IBM® Domino®](http://de.slideshare.net/sbasegmez/iconuk-2013-an-xpagers-guide-to-process-serverside-jobs-on-ibm-domino)